# how to connect to R Shiny website using programming

Tags: r, shiny

We have a R shiny based website where we input some parameters and get some results. We can do it manually, but considering many actions are repeat, we want write some R code to automatically pull out the results. Look looks we cannot use some simple REST request, because the HTTP request used some information like "nonce" and "session". Also I am not familiar with the JavaScript. Could someone help me to understand how to do it?[image]

Comment: Seems like it is running on the localhost (or that’s kinda socks-proxy?). Either way I would suggest to copy cookie and check out what you have in headers (spoofing cookie is sufficient in 90% of cases, but sometimes there is something in headers that getting checked). You also have option to “copy request as CURL”, and dig into the authorization process and seek CSRF-related stuff.

Comment: Almost forgot: do they have dedicated REST API endpoints? It worth of double checking

Answer (score 2):

There is a functionality `session$registerDataObj` which allows you to add an API endpoint for a specific shiny session. This will make the provided data available at `http://{host}/session/{session_id}/dataobj/{name}`.

The minimal app below invokes the produced endpoint via `browseURL()`. See `?shiny::session` for more details.

```r
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    name <- "iris"
    session$registerDataObj(
      name = name, 
      data = iris, 
      filterFunc = function(data, req) { 
        httpResponse(content = paste('nrow: ', nrow(data))) 
      }
    )
    uri <- paste0("http://", session$request$HTTP_HOST, "/session/", 
                  session$token, "/dataobj/", name)
    browseURL(print(uri))
  }
)
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5130
#> [1] "http://127.0.0.1:5130/session/fd47ff29025bbe4d9dbf922b935186b3/dataobj/iris"
```

This should open up a new browser tab that shows: "nrow: 150". The return value of `session$registerDataObj()` can also be used to create the `uri` with additional query parameters.

But I personally think it is better to use a database in 99% of all usecases. This would mean that there is an export button in your ui which causes the app server to write all relevant results into the database and the database is then accessed by another process that needs the app data.